# Add text to a point in image swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimageview

I am using UITapGestureRecognizer to get coordinates in a UIImageView, then use that coordinates as a position where to add text to image. The problem the text was not added exactly to where I touched on UIImageView
Could you help me to solve problem or give me some suggest

```
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: documentsPath + "/bach.jpg")
        let imageViewTapped = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapAction(_:)))
        imageViewTapped.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        imageViewTapped.delegate = self
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(imageViewTapped)
    }

    func tapAction(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let point = sender.location(in: self.imageView)
        print("x \(point.x) y \(point.y) ")
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        let image = UIImage(named: documentsPath + "/bach.jpg")!
        let newImage = textToImage(drawText: "㊗️Hello", inImage: image, atPoint: CGPoint(x: point.x, y: point.y))
        imageView.image = newImage
    }

    // Add text to image
    func textToImage(drawText text: NSString, inImage image: UIImage, atPoint point: CGPoint) -> UIImage {
        let textColor = UIColor.white
        let textFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 300)!
        let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, scale)

        let textFontAttributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName: textFont,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
            ] as [String : Any]
        image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: image.size))
        text.draw(at: point, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage!
    }
```

Comment: Try replacing image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: image.size)) with  
image.draw(in: imageView.frame)

Comment: @AravindAR its not wokring, after changed the base image become smaller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {
let lblNew = UILabel()
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: documentsPath + "/bach.jpg")
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let imageViewTapped = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapAction(_:)))
    imageViewTapped.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    imageViewTapped.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(imageViewTapped)
}

func tapAction(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let point = sender.location(in: self.imageView)
    print("x \(point.x) y \(point.y) ")
    textToImage(drawText: "㊗️Hello", atPoint: CGPoint(x: point.x, y: point.y))

}

// Add text to image
func textToImage(drawText text: NSString, atPoint point: CGPoint) {

    lblNew.frame = CGRect(x: point.x, y: point.y, width: 200.0, height: 10)
    lblNew.textAlignment = .left
    lblNew.text = text as String
    lblNew.textColor = UIColor.white
    imageView.addSubview(lblNew)
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you again. One more question, what I should do to save the edited image. Your solution is create a subview right ??

Comment: No need of subview, first of all where do u want to save it? I mean do u want to save it in document directory or gallery?

Comment: Thank for reply, just want to save it in document directory

Answer (score 1):

Code to save image in document directly in png format. If you want to save it in jpeg formate then just change that UIImagePNGRepresentation line into UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9).

```
func saveImage()
{
    if let image = UIImage(named: "test.png") {
        if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
            let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("copy.png")
            try? data.write(to: filename)
        }
    }
}

func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

Comment: you are so kind for helping me, but is that code save the edited image?. Ex. I touch a position on screen and using your above code to add text or something to that position. Finally save all of that to a png file. I run your code and it does not save the image without any text I put on it

Comment: i am not clear what you are saying, do you want to save image along with text what it has?

Comment: sorry because of my bad english. "do you want to save image along with text what it has" ← yes

Answer (score 1):

```
Replace your saveImage method with the following code snippet.

func saveImage()
{
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
  imageView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
  let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

  if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!) {
        let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("copy.png")
        try? data.write(to: filename)
    }
}
```